# Use Entity Framework with SQL Server in UWP

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, uwp

I am starting to learn UWP platform. In first steps I want to do simple application (bookshop). Unfortunately, I got stuck on steps: how to use Entity Framework with SQL Server in UWP?

First I was using

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

but I got lots of conflicts (ex. `System.Threading.Thread 4.3.0`  error, *or One or more packages are incompatible with UAP,Version=v10.0 (win10-x86).*).

After that, I was trying add a classic dll to project (and install ef), but... classic library are incompatible with UWP...

Do you have any idea how to use EF with SQL Server in UWP ? I don't want to use sqlite...

Comment: Someone maged to connect using TCP/IP
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869499/error-using-entity-framework-core-with-sql-server-on-uwp-app?noredirect=1#comment86805044_49869499

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry you can only use the entity framework SQLite provider with UWP.

Comment: I have tried to install `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` in my UWP application but encountered the same issues.  I guess it's still in infancy stage to use EF Core.SqlServer, but Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlLite works.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Windows SDK (**Falls Creators Update**) will support direct **SQL Server** connection. Have a look at it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

Comment: The question asks about EF and the article says nothing about EF. If I posted a short answer like that then I would get voted down.

Answer (score 0):

To use SQLite in your UWP app, you need to target **Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0; Build 16299)**

The NuGet packages are:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

I successfully connected ms sql, entity framework to uwp.
They work together.

To connect, I used an additional project "csproj" with the standard .NetStandard 2.0 in the same solution. I also used "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" in this project, not in the UWP project. It was just class library

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).