# Error using Entity Framework Core with SQL Server on UWP app

Tags: uwp, entity-framework-core

I have a data project (.net standard 2.0) with Entity FrameWork Core 2.0.2 and SQL Server, Sqlite and PostgreSql providers.

I have more three projects for presentation in Windows Forms, WPF and UWP.

When I run the Windows Forms and WPF, Entity Framework Core works fine for all providers, but when I try to run the SQL Server provider on UWP, it throw this

[image]

The error occurred in the method `EnsureCreatedAsync`:

```
public async Task InitDataBaseAsync(DataBaseConfig config)
{
   using (var db = GetDataContext(config))
   {
      // Postgresql and Sqlite do not throw exception in UWP.
      await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();
   }
}
```

I checked the three platforms connection string, the connection are the same.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: Is the server running on the same machine as the app? UWP has some restrictions regarding this...

Comment: Yes, running on my localhost

Comment: Have you checked the Enterprise [Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) option In the Capabilities tab?

Comment: I had not checked, but after checking the error persist  When I use  data project on windows forms work normally

Comment: The inner exception show : The operation completed successfully and stacktrace >>    at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(String browserHostName, String instanceName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel)

Comment: My workaround is to enable TCP / IP by the SQL server configuration Manager and my connection string now uses Data Source = 127.0.0.1,1433; ... now it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the connection string to use **TCP/IP**

**Before**

```
Data Source=xpt/SqlServerExpress;Initial Catalog=gestao_eficaz;User ID=sa;Password=somePassword
```

**After**

```
Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433;Initial Catalog=gestao_eficaz;User ID=sa;Password=somePassword
```

It is also necessary to enable the TCP / IP connection in the sql server

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388042/connect-to-sql-server-2008-with-tcp-ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869499/error-using-entity-framework-core-with-sql-server-on-uwp-app?noredirect=1#comment86805044_49869499)

Now works !!!

Answer (score 1):

Enabling and starting the SQL Browser service fixed the problem for me. That avoids messing around with IP addresses and TCP ports.

Integrated security would not work, however, I had to revert to SQL User ID and password.